# How to build our own tokens in acejs editor

Tags: token, ace-editor

In acejs editor, we have a lot of build-in tokens, like string, command, and keyword. We can give different color and event handler according to tokens. Here, I wonder it's possible to create our own customer tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ace doesn't give any special meaning to tokens any string can be a token.

Comment: Thank you, and do you know how to give the color to token. For example, whenever I typed something belong to "hex" token must display as green.

Comment: add a css rule for `.ace_hex {color: green}`, Use `.ace_tm .ace_hex {color: green}` if you only want to apply color to textmate theme.